# Migrating from Hive Map to Snowflake Variant

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, variant

We are migrating our code from Hive to Snowflake and so hive map is migrated to snowflake variant. However when we loaded data into snowflake table - we are seeing addition KEY and VALUE string in our data.

Hive MAP data -
{"SD10":"","SD9":""}

SnowSQL Variant data -
[    {      "key": "SD10",      "value": ""    },    {      "key": "SD9",      "value": ""    }]

I am using stage and ORC file to load data from Hadoop to Snowflake.

Is there a way we can store the map data as it is into snowflake variant. Basically I don't want additional KEY and VALUE strings

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the PARSE_JSON function:

```
-- Returns { "SD10": "", "SD9": "" }
select parse_json('{"SD10":"","SD9":""}') as JSON;
```

You can add this to your COPY INTO statement. You can see different options for this in the Snowflake example for Parquet files, which is very similar to loading ORC files in Snowflake: https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/script-data-load-transform-parquet.html.

You can also find more information on transformations on load here: https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/data-load-transform.html

Comment: I tried the option you suggested; however getting error - 100069 (22P02): Error parsing JSON: missing first byte in UTF-8 sequence, pos 87

My copy code is -

copy into  abc1
from (select 
$1:_col0  ::varchar,
$1:_col1 ::varchar,
$1:_col2 ::varchar,
$1:_col3 ::varchar,
parse_json($1:_col4) ::varchar,
$1:_col5 ::varchar,
$1:_col6 ::varchar,
$1:_col7 ::varchar,
$1:_col8 ::varchar,
$1:_col9 ::varchar,
$1:_col10 ::varchar,
$1:_col11 ::varchar,
$1:_col12 ::varchar
from @abc/)
FILE_FORMAT = ( TYPE = ORC)
TRUNCATECOLUMNS = TRUE
;
Please help.

Comment: You can add ON_ERROR = CONTINUE to see if it's just one or more rows failing or if the conversion fails all the time. After running that you can use the VALIDATE command to return all errors rather than just the first one. https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/validate.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. My stage data itself has KEY VALUE headers and also even after adding ON_ERROR = CONTINUE - it's throwing exception. Any idea why Hive map data is getting converted like this in Snowflake stage?                           Hive MAP data - {"SD10":"","SD9":""}
SnowSQL Variant data - [ { "key": "SD10", "value": "" }, { "key": "SD9", "value": "" }]

Comment: No, sorry, not sure without looking at the data, etc. Seems like one for Snowflake support.

Comment: oh ok ..Thanks for the help. Trying the work arounds.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with UDF.

```
create or replace function list_to_dict(v variant)
    returns variant
    language javascript
    as'
        function listToDict(input){
            var returnDictionary = {}
            var inputLength = input.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < inputLength; i++) {
                returnDictionary[input[i]["key"]] = input[i]["value"]
            }
            return returnDictionary
        }
        return listToDict(V);
    ';

select list_to_dict(column)['SD10'] from table;
```